# How to post the time ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, fetch

I explain my problem of the day

in the following code, I post objects

my question, is it possible to post the time at which the post was made?

```
postbackend = () =>{
const config = {    
method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify({...this.state, items:this.props.items}),
};
const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls"; 
fetch(url, config)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  if (res.error) {
    alert(res.error);
  } else {
    alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
  }
}).catch(e => {
  console.error(e);
}).finally(()=>this.setState({ redirect: true }));
}
```

I would simply like to recover the time at which the post was made
Do you have an idea of how to fix this? Neff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body: JSON.stringify({...this.state, created: new Date().toISOString(), items:this.props.items})
```

This will add the timestamp to the POST body.

You should take into consideration the fact this is considered to be a bad practice. Because users might have different time on their computers. That could lead to inconsistencies. The best way to solve the problem would be to set up the date/time on the server.

Comment: ok great, for me it's going to be time to eat, I try this after eating and I come back to you thank you

Comment: post function but reponse on bdd is "1582032919591" is not time ?

Comment: ok this time is work , can abuse pls ? if i want to french time ? and second question , it is possible only show hour i dont really need date ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
postbackend = () => {
    startDate = new Date(); // add this date
    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            ...this.state,
            items: this.props.items
        }),
    };
    const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
    fetch(url, config)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            if (res.error) {
                alert(res.error);
            } else {
                alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
            }
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        }).finally(() => this.setState({
            redirect: true
        }));
    return startDate; // return it
}
```

After that you get a date for each `postbackend`:

```
const date1 = postbackend();
const date2 = postbackend();
const date3 = postbackend();
```

You can save them in a list

```
const dates = [];
dates.push(postbackend());
```

Persist them to a DB and so on

Comment: ok great, for me it's going to be time to eat, I try this after eating and I come back to you thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the time with the request you could just add it to the body of the request like so:

```
JSON.stringify({...this.state, items:this.props.items, postTime: Date.now()})
```

`Date.now()` returns the time in milliseconds since 1st January 1970. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

If you want to format it to a string you can do the following:

```js
const dateNow = Date.now(); // Date in milliseconds since 1st January 1970
const date = new Date(dateNow); //Creates a date object from the milliseconds

console.log(dateNow); 
console.log(date);
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));
```

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: ok great, for me it's going to be time to eat, I try this after eating and I come back to you thank you